# Merge Array based on Conditions in php

Tags: php

I am just start learning php and creating a project using php. In my code i am creating web service using php and needs to be merged the array and create on array. The last output should come in json.
When i print the first array it looks:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [chapter_name] => Algebra
            [chapter_id] => 1
            [module_id] => 12
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [chapter_name] => Combinatorics
            [chapter_id] => 2
            [module_id] => 12
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [chapter_name] => Mathematical physics
            [chapter_id] => 3
            [module_id] => 12
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [chapter_name] => Calculus and analysis
            [chapter_id] => 6
            [module_id] => 12
        )

)
```

The second Array is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [unimodule_name] => Artificial Intelligence
            [module_id] => 7
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [unimodule_name] => Camp
            [module_id] => 11
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [unimodule_name] => Mathematics
            [module_id] => 12
        )

)
```

I want the final output should be in json and like:

```
[
  {
    moduleName: "Camp",
    chapters: [

    ],

  },
  {
    moduleName: "Artificial Intelligence",
    chapters: [

    ],

  },
  {
    moduleName: "Mathematics",
    chapters: [
      {
        Chaptername: "test"
      },
      {
        Chaptername: Calculusandanalysis
      },
      {
        Chaptername: Algebra
      },
      {
        Chaptername: Combinatorics
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is code:

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select unimodules.name as unimodule_name, unimodules.id as unimodule_id from unimodules WHERE course_id = 5 AND unimodules.name IS NOT NULL"));

    print_r($results); // first array

foreach ($results as $result) {

    $chapters = [];

    $chapters = DB::select( DB::raw("select chapters.name as chapter_name, chapters.id as chapter_id, chapters.module_id from chapters WHERE module_id = ".$result->unimodule_id.""));

}
    print_r($chapters); // second array

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $results,
        'message' => 'course_success',
        'status' => 200
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please show some coding effort what you have tried so far to make us believe that you tried something at least. Otherwise, it seems like you are asking us to write code for you.[Check this how can you ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Question updated..

Comment: Second `print_r($results); ` needs to be `print_r($chapters);` . don't you think so?

Comment: yes....u are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your second `foreach()` code (which is used for getting chapters) like this:-

```
$final_array = []; //define your final array what you want at end
foreach ($results as $result) {

    $final_array[$result->unimodule_name]['moduleName'] = $result->unimodule_name; // assign module name to the final array

    $chapters = DB::select( DB::raw("select chapters.name as chapter_name, chapters.id as chapter_id, chapters.module_id from chapters WHERE module_id = ".$result->unimodule_id.""));

    if(count($chapters)>0){
        foreach($chapters as $chapter){
            $final_array[$result->unimodule_name]['chapters'][] = ['Chaptername'=>$chapter->chapter_name]; //assign all chapters to corresponding module

        }
    }else{
        $final_array[$result->unimodule_name]['chapters'] = [];
    }

}

$final_array = array_values($final_array); // remove associative array key indexes

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array); // print to check you got desired output or not
```